# Opening entity from external iframe CRM 2013

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

We have a CRM 2011 solution with several custom ASP.NET MVC-based views and forms that are displayed in iframes on entities in CRM. Currently we're doing some analysis on upgrading to CRM 2013, and we've run into a problem with opening entity windows.

We have mostly used `window.open` throughout the solution, both in JavaScripts on the CRM side of things, and in the custom ASP.NET MVC application. The URL passed to `window.open` is in the following format:

```
http://crm.contoso.com/Contoso-Org/main.aspx?etn=opportunity&pagetype=entityrecord&id={...}
```

The problem is that this seems to remember the context when it's opened in CRM 2013, so it just reopens the entity it was opened from. We solved this on the CRM end by using `Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm` instead, but it doesn't seem as if that is possible for the custom application, as we don't have access to the Xrm library from inside the iframe. The URL is correct, and if it's copy pasted into a new tab, it correctly loads the desired entity. When loaded with `window.open` though, it just reopens the same entity.

Some suggestions have pointed to appending a `histKey` parameter consisting of a randomly generated number to the opened URL. However, this does not work consistently - sometimes it opens the correct entity, sometimes it just reopens the current entity - nor is it officially documented anywhere.

Has anyone come across a solution to this?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question.  It sounds like you've fixed the issue loading from within CRM, but from your MVC, it isn't working?  If you're opening up a new window from an external app, what is the "same entity"?

Comment: Let's say I'm viewing an Opportunity record. There, we have an iframe displaying our MVC application. The MVC application contains an `<a>` which is supposed to open the Account that the Opportunity is related to. The `etn` parameter is set to `account` and the GUID points to the Account entity. However, when clicking the URL, it just opens the same Opportunity it was opened from instead. So it somehow "remembers" the context it came from, even if it's opened in a new tab. CRM seems to append a hash code which is identical, so there's possibly some internal state at play.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similiar issue with opening CRM 2013 URLs and was able to fix it by adding two query strings **histKey** (which takes a random number as value) and **newWindow** to the URL, as follows:

- `"histKey=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)`
- `"newWindow=true"`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Change the A tag target to _blank
2. Give the window a new name  i.e. open(url, new_name, features)
3. A workaround might be to create an IFRAME inside your MVC app and pass the URL back to a CRM form which eventually open the account form.
4. Use Wscript.Shell ActiveX to open a new IE process (last resort).
5. This link might help 
   http://steveliles.github.io/cross_domain_inter_frame_communication_in_javascript.html

HTH

[Dynamics CRM - Thinking outside the BOX](http://totbcrm.blogspot.com/)